# how to close a div in a dynamic group?

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop, left-join

With mysql left-join I have a result of 3 tables.
Every group of machine-types has special requirements. Some machine-types have the same requirements, some not.

My problem is, to list them grouped and clear adressable for css-styling. I want to show all groups - with its requirements - but the group as header only one time.

How can I output and place a closing div to the right position?

```
$lastDate = ''; 


while($r = $result_all->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

    $aktualisiert = $r->MTypID;


    if ( $aktualisiert != $lastDate ){ 


    echo '<div class="machine-type">'.$r->mtype'</div>';
    echo '<div class="requirements">';


    $lastDate = $aktualisiert; 


    }  


    //if ( $aktualisiert = $lastDate ){ 
    echo $r->baustand." ";

    //}

 }//endwhile
```

Output should be like this (see `*</div>*`):

```
<div class="machine-type">Model 1</div><div class="requirements">Softwareupdate 2.4.0 Valve M4 Tube 20cm *</div>*
<div class="machine-type">Model 2</div><div class="requirements">Softwareupdate 2.4.0 *</div>*
```

Comment: Do you mean `echo $r->baustand." "; if ( $aktualisiert === $lastDate ) {echo "</div>";}`? Be aware that `=` is an assignment while `===` and `==` are comparisions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Quasimodo's clone! I did not think of that. Cool, just corrected in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to close the div when `$lastDate` changes, but not when it is the first row in the output. So after

```
if ( $aktualisiert != $lastDate ){
```

add

```
if ( $lastDate != '' ) echo "</div>";
```

and then after your loop add

```
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

With adding of a separator (also a bit tricky), it's more useful.
Here the final code - maybe interesting to somebody...

```php
$lastDate = ''; 
$separator ='+';
$space =' ';

while($r = $result_all->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

    $aktualisiert = $r->MTypID;

    if ( $aktualisiert == $lastDate ) echo $separator.$space;

    if ( $aktualisiert !== $lastDate ){ 

    if ( $lastDate !== '' ) echo '</div>'; //<!-- end requirements 1/2 --> 

    echo '<div class="machine-type">'.htmlspecialchars($r->mtype)'</div>';;
    echo '<div class="requirements">';

    $lastDate = $aktualisiert; 

    }

    echo htmlspecialchars($r->baustand).' ';

}//endwhile
echo '</div>'; //<!-- end requirements 2/2 -->
```